# Erro ao inserir dados nas tabelas do MySQL

Tags: mysql

Quando eu insiro os dados nas tabelas aparece o seguinte erro:

**ERROR CODE: 1265, data truncate for column 'genero' at row 13**

Como resolve esse erro?

```
create database sf;
use sf;

create table time1(
    id_time1 int primary key not null,
    nome varchar(50),
    arte_marcial varchar(50),
    pais_origem varchar(50),
    genero enum('M','F'),
    data_nascimento date,
    altura decimal (3,2),
    peso decimal (5,2)
);

insert into time1 (id_time1, nome, arte_marcial, pais_origem, genero, data_nascimento, altura, peso)
values
(1,'Ryu','Ansatsuken','Japão','M','1964-07-21',1.75,84.00),
(2,'Ken','Ansatsuken','USA','M','1965-02-14',1.80,72.00),
(3,'Chun-Li','Wushu','China','F','1968-01-03',1.78,63.00),
(4,'Akuma','Ansatsuken','Japão','M','1945-06-21',1.82,90.00),
(5,'Guile','Técnicas Militares','USA','M','1960-12-23',1.65,96.00),
(6,'Cammy White','Delta Red','Inglaterra','F','1974-01-06',1.52,60.00),
(7,'Honda','Sumô','Japão','M','1960-11-03',1.85,137.00),
(8,'Fei Long','Kung Fu','China','M','1969-04-23',1.72,60.00),
(9,'Blanka','Capoeira','Brasil','M','1966-02-12',1.92,96.00),
(10,'Vega','Ninjitsu Espanhol','Espanha','M','1967-01-27',1.86,72.00),
(11,'Dhalsim','Kabbadi','Índia','M','1952-11-22',1.76,48.00),
(12,'Balrog','Boxe','USA','M','1968-09-04',1.98,102.00),
(13,'Mr. Bison','Psycho Power','Tailândia','M','1945-04-17',1.77,112.00),
(14,'Sagat','Muay Thai','Tailândia','M','1955-07-02',2.26,109.00),
(15,'Zangief','Sambo','Rússia','M','1956-06-01',2.13,180.00)

create table time2(
    id_time2 int primary key not null,
    nome varchar(50),
    arte_marcial varchar(50),
    pais_origem varchar(50),
    genero enum('M','F'),
    data_nascimento date,
    altura decimal (3,2),
    peso decimal (5,2)
);

insert into time2 (id_time2, nome, arte_marcial, pais_origem, genero, data_nascimento, altura, peso)
values
(1,'T.Hawk','Luta Indígena','USA','M','1959-07-21',2.30,162.00),
(2,'Dee Jay','Kickboxing','USA','M','1965-10-31',1.84,92.00),
(3,'Rainbow Mika','Wrestling','Japão','F','1969-05-27',1.68,69.00),
(4,'Sakura','Ansatsuken','Japão','F','1973-03-15',1.57,42.00),
(5,'Karin','Kanzukiryu Kakutoujutsu','Japão','F','1973-09-15',1.62,48.00),
(6,'Juri','Tae Kwon Do','Coréia do Sul','F','1970-01-01',1.65,46.00),
(7,'Nash','Técnicas Militares','USA','M','1962-11-01',1.86,93.00),
(8,'Ibuki','Ninjitsu','Japão','F','1979-12-06',1.62,55.00),
(9,'Elena','Capoeira','Quênia','F','1981-09-18',1.83,54.00),
(10,'Laura','Jiu-Jitsu','Brasil','F','1986-07-30',1.75,72.00),
(11,'Rose','Soul Power','Itália','F','1957-07-03',1.78,54.00),
(12,'Hugo Andore','Whestling','Alemanha','M','1964-05-19',2.40,260.00),
(13,'Poison','Luta Acrobática Autodidata','USA','T','1978-12-07',1.75,52.00),
(14,'Alex','Whestling','USA','M','1970-05-15',1.95,111.000),
(15,'Adon','Muay Thai','Tailândia','M','1967-06-28',1.82,73.00)

create table cenario(
    id_cenario int primary key not null,
    nome_cenario varchar (50),
    pais_cenario varchar (50),
    id_time1 int,
    id_time2 int,
    foreign key (id_time1) references time1 (id_time1),
    foreign key (id_time2) references time2 (id_time2)
);

insert into cenario (id_cenario, nome_cenario, pais_cenario, id_time1, id_time2)
values
(1,'Matsue Castle','Japão',1,1),
(2,'Wan Chai','China',2,2),
(3,'Thrissur Pooram Festival','Índia',3,3),
(4,'Ayutthaya','Tailândia',4,4),
(5,'Hakone Kowakien Yunessun','Japão',5,5),
(6,'Parque Museo La Venta','México',6,6),
(7,'Lichtenstein Castle','Alemanha',7,7),
(8,'Manaus','Brasil',8,8),
(9,'Edradour Distillery','Escócia',9,9),
(10,'The Golden Nugget Hotel and Casino','USA',10,10),
(11,'Vulcão Kilawea','USA',11,11),
(12,'Mykonos','Grécia',12,12),
(13,'San Francisco','USA',13,13),
(14,'Todaiji Temple','Japão',14,14),
(15,'Novosibirsk','Rússia',15,15)
```

Comment: (13,'Poison','Luta Acrobática Autodidata','USA','T','1978-12-07',1.75,52.00). O gênero "**T**" por um acaso está correto?

Comment: É mesmo, por causa que **Poison** na franquia ela é **transsexual**. Realmente não tinha percebido isso, vou alterar aqui.

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva muito obrigado, o problema era esse mesmo e agora tudo está resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base no que @CaiodePaulaSilva disse ficaria assim:

```
create database sf;
use sf;

create table time1(
    id_time1 int primary key not null,
    nome varchar(50),
    arte_marcial varchar(50),
    pais_origem varchar(50),
    genero enum('M','F','T'), # Linha alterada
    data_nascimento date,
    altura decimal (3,2),
    peso decimal (5,2)
);

insert into time1 (id_time1, nome, arte_marcial, pais_origem, genero, data_nascimento, altura, peso)
values
(1,'Ryu','Ansatsuken','Japão','M','1964-07-21',1.75,84.00),
(2,'Ken','Ansatsuken','USA','M','1965-02-14',1.80,72.00),
(3,'Chun-Li','Wushu','China','F','1968-01-03',1.78,63.00),
(4,'Akuma','Ansatsuken','Japão','M','1945-06-21',1.82,90.00),
(5,'Guile','Técnicas Militares','USA','M','1960-12-23',1.65,96.00),
(6,'Cammy White','Delta Red','Inglaterra','F','1974-01-06',1.52,60.00),
(7,'Honda','Sumô','Japão','M','1960-11-03',1.85,137.00),
(8,'Fei Long','Kung Fu','China','M','1969-04-23',1.72,60.00),
(9,'Blanka','Capoeira','Brasil','M','1966-02-12',1.92,96.00),
(10,'Vega','Ninjitsu Espanhol','Espanha','M','1967-01-27',1.86,72.00),
(11,'Dhalsim','Kabbadi','Índia','M','1952-11-22',1.76,48.00),
(12,'Balrog','Boxe','USA','M','1968-09-04',1.98,102.00),
(13,'Mr. Bison','Psycho Power','Tailândia','M','1945-04-17',1.77,112.00),
(14,'Sagat','Muay Thai','Tailândia','M','1955-07-02',2.26,109.00),
(15,'Zangief','Sambo','Rússia','M','1956-06-01',2.13,180.00)

create table time2(
    id_time1 int primary key not null,
    nome varchar(50),
    arte_marcial varchar(50),
    pais_origem varchar(50),
    genero enum('M','F','T'), # Linha alterada
    data_nascimento date,
    altura decimal (3,2),
    peso decimal (5,2)
);

insert into time2 (id_time2, nome, arte_marcial, pais_origem, genero, data_nascimento, altura, peso)
values
(1,'T.Hawk','Luta Indígena','USA','M','1959-07-21',2.30,162.00),
(2,'Dee Jay','Kickboxing','USA','M','1965-10-31',1.84,92.00),
(3,'Rainbow Mika','Wrestling','Japão','F','1969-05-27',1.68,69.00),
(4,'Sakura','Ansatsuken','Japão','F','1973-03-15',1.57,42.00),
(5,'Karin','Kanzukiryu Kakutoujutsu','Japão','F','1973-09-15',1.62,48.00),
(6,'Juri','Tae Kwon Do','Coréia do Sul','F','1970-01-01',1.65,46.00),
(7,'Nash','Técnicas Militares','USA','M','1962-11-01',1.86,93.00),
(8,'Ibuki','Ninjitsu','Japão','F','1979-12-06',1.62,55.00),
(9,'Elena','Capoeira','Quênia','F','1981-09-18',1.83,54.00),
(10,'Laura','Jiu-Jitsu','Brasil','F','1986-07-30',1.75,72.00),
(11,'Rose','Soul Power','Itália','F','1957-07-03',1.78,54.00),
(12,'Hugo Andore','Whestling','Alemanha','M','1964-05-19',2.40,260.00),
(13,'Poison','Luta Acrobática Autodidata','USA','T','1978-12-07',1.75,52.00),
(14,'Alex','Whestling','USA','M','1970-05-15',1.95,111.00),
(15,'Adon','Muay Thai','Tailândia','M','1967-06-28',1.82,73.00)

insert into cenario (id_cenario, nome_cenario, pais_cenario, id_time1, id_time2)
values
(1,'Matsue Castle','Japão',1,1),
(2,'Wan Chai','China',2,2),
(3,'Thrissur Pooram Festival','Índia',3,3),
(4,'Ayutthaya','Tailândia',4,4),
(5,'Hakone Kowakien Yunessun','Japão',5,5),
(6,'Parque Museo La Venta','México',6,6),
(7,'Lichtenstein Castle','Alemanha',7,7),
(8,'Manaus','Brasil',8,8),
(9,'Edradour Distillery','Escócia',9,9),
(10,'The Golden Nugget Hotel and Casino','USA',10,10),
(11,'Vulcão Kilawea','USA',11,11),
(12,'Mykonos','Grécia',12,12),
(13,'San Francisco','USA',13,13),
(14,'Todaiji Temple','Japão',14,14),
(15,'Novosibirsk','Rússia',15,15)
```